How to get rid of pages merging up in ms-word 2016
I am writing a research paper and all the pages in my work have been merged up. The pages are separated only with thin lines, but I want to see pages on new sheets. How do I solve this problem?

are you in print layout mode? the controls to change between "reader mode", "Print Layout mode" and "Web layout mode" are on the bottom bar, at the right (at least in my locality) next to the zoom bar. alternately you can press Ctrl+Alt+P
